# Deleting Faces "inside" a mesh

Tags: faces

[image]

I have a question, how do i delete the selected face ?
"Delete faces" doesn't help as the face is still there as soon as i go into object mode - i considered using the knife tool but that seems a bit too "clumsy" for me - as i want some kind of curve to be preserved.

i would appreciate any help, thank you

Cheers

Comment: hello, please share your object: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Looks like the geometry of the two N-gons surrounding the face is making the N-gons bridge between the newly opened spaces. Try to select the two other faces and use 'poke faces' (under the faces tab in the top of the viewport). This will try to divide the n-gons up into tri's and quads.